# IIS 6 redirects my site to another site in IIS when I assign an IP address to it

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, iis-6, ip, redirect

I'm having a bit of difficulty with IIS 6.

IIS has about 10 or so different websites running on the server I've been given access to and the host have provided me with a new "external" IP and new "internal" IP.

I've set DNS to point to the external one and that all seems to be okay. However, when I set the IP address on IIS to point to the internal one they created I find that my site is being redirected to one of the other sites on the server (one that's already had a completely different IP assigned).

Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me clues on what I may be doing wrong please?

The IP Config on the machine looks like this:

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 5.2.3790]
(C) Copyright 1985-2003 Microsoft Corp.



Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SERVER1
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Accelerated AMD PCNet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-97-24-41
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.5.53
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.5.52
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.5.51
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.5.49
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 194.247.65.2
                                       194.247.64.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Accelerated AMD PCNet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-97-5A-75
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration IP Address. . . : 169.254.62.57
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I've been told to use the IP ending in 53.

Hope someone can help,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Assuming you are using a fully qualified domain name to access the website, make sure that FQDN is added as a host header entry for your website
- Also add the external IP address to your site as a host header file entry and try browsing to that external IP address from outside your network. Does it still redirect to the other site?
- Add the internal IP address as a host header file entry and try browsing that IP right from the webserver.
- Then check the host header file entries for the site that requests are being redirected to. Make sure that for whatever reason neither your website's public IP or FQDN are added (perhaps by mistake when they provisioned your site, etc.)
- Once you're satisfied that your internal configuartion is solid, it's likely a Network Address Transalation issue. Confirm your firewall's forwarding the right external IP's & ports to the right internal IP's and ports